# How to pass parameter in Angularjs controller from handlebars file(.hbs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars as my view templates with the mix of Angularjs. I am stuck in a situation where I have a loop in which I am displaying all the elements as clickable url which when clicked should pass the value to controller.

Code I have written:

```
 <tbody>

{{#each continueDiscovery}}
    <tr>
        <td headers="name"><a href="" ng-model="result" ng-value={{productName}} ng-click="productDiscovery(result)">{{productName}}</a></td>
        <td headers="name"><a href="">{{user}}</a></td>
    </tr>

{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Angular.js controller code:

```
$scope.productDiscovery = function(productName){



    alert("Task Id is "+productName);
    var productName = $scope.productName;

    console.log($scope.productName)
    console.log(productName)


};
```

But I keep getting the `productName` as `undefined`.

Comment: As a test replace <a> with: `<input ng-model="result" value="Blah"><button ng-click="="productDiscovery(result)"></button>` to make sure things are working then we can take it from there.

Comment: @camden_kid: No I still get the same error.

Comment: seems you have a model called 'result' to which you would like to assign the value of 'productName', in your code you are trying to passing 'result' - the model, into a function? Not sure if that's your intention. Anyhoo. Being that your model is named 'result' you should probably be logging ` $scope.result` to get it's value of `productName`

Comment: and you may also need to change `var productName = $scope.productName;` to `var productName = $scope.result;`
`

Comment: OK, so what I suggest is that you don't pass result as a parameter (in fact, there is no need) but just directly access $scope.result within $scope.productDiscovery: `console.log($scope.result)`

Comment: i would also agree with the above comment that you do not need to pass the function a parameter at all, at least at this point

Comment: I already have tried with both the options but I still get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 <tbody>

{{#each continueDiscovery}}
    <tr>
        <td headers="name"><a href="" ng-model="result" ng-value={{productName}} ng-click="productDiscovery()">{{productName}}</a></td>
        <td headers="name"><a href="">{{user}}</a></td>
    </tr>

{{/each}}
</tbody>


var productName = $scope.result;

$scope.productDiscovery = function(){
    alert("Task Id is "+productName);
};
```

Comment: No I still see the same value "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars have the same syntax of printing the data and takes the precedence over Angular when using both.

```
<tbody>

{{#each continueDiscovery}}
    <tr>
        <td headers="name"><a href="" name="productName" ng-click="productDiscovery('{{productName}}')">{{productName}}</a></td>
        <td headers="name"><a href="">{{user}}</a></td>
    </tr>

{{/each}}
</tbody>
```